# Determine if string is all caps with regular expression

Tags: regex

How can you determine if a string is all caps with a regular expression.  It can include punctuation and numbers, just no lower case letters.

Comment: probably not the best use of a regex....

Comment: @Mitch Can you elaborate on that? Looks like a valid case for regex to me.

Comment: How about empty lines?  Some of the answers here reject them, but it's an interesting edge case.

Comment: This regex will be true for strings like "@#$@#" or any numeric string. You'll have to add more to it if you're allowing user input to ensure they don't have a string that is all numbers or symbols.

Answer (score 28):

```
m/^[^a-z]*$/
```

For non-English characters,

```
m/^\P{Ll}*$/
```

(`\P{Ll}` is the same as `[^\p{Ll}]`, which accepts all characters except the ones marked as lower-case.)

Comment: It's worth noting perhaps, that this will also match strings with no caps, and just numbers, or just punctuation, or blank strings etc.

Comment: @Totem
you can just check the above regex in addition to

`m/[a-zA-z]/` 

to eliminate empty string / just numbers / just punctuation etc...

Comment: The multiline (m/) flag is solving a problem that was not explicitly introduced in this question and may be undesirable some readers.

Comment: @Dan The leading `m/` is not the multi-line flag (that would be trailing `/m`), but the Perl syntax to indicate it is a "match".

Comment: `m/^[^\p{Ll}]*$/`  doesn't work for languages that don't have a distinction between upper/lower case.  E.g., Japanese or Chinese

Comment: @simpleCoder Japanese and Chinese characters do not belong to the `Ll` category, thus `\p{Ll}` will *not match* the CJK characters, and thus the complement `[^\p{Ll}]` will *match* the CJK characters. Depending on what you mean by "work".

Answer (score 10):

That sounds like you want: `^[^a-z]*$`

Comment: This will only match strings of exactly one character in length.

Comment: Good idea, but that won't work for strings that does not contain letters. i.e. `1, 2, 3` will be detected as "all caps"

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul: the question says: "It can include punctuation and numbers, just no lower case letters."

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use if(string.toUpperCase() == string)? ._. Its more "elegant"...
I think you're trying to force in RegExp, but as someone else stated, I don't think this is the best use of regexp...

Comment: How do you use that, for example, to extract all satisfactory lines with a `grep`?

Comment: string.toUpperCase() == string returns true for strings like '@#$%' which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: He is asking how to do this using regex. I don't understand upvotes on this answer. And regex is more elegant and cover more requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the string against another regex after making sure that there are no lower case letters, you can use positive lookahead.

```
^(?=[^a-z]*$)MORE_REGEX$
```

For example, to make sure that first and last characters are alpha-numeric:

```
^(?=[^a-z]*$)[A-Z0-9].*[A-Z0-9]$
```

Answer (score 1):

The string contains a lowercase letter if the expression `/[a-z]/` returns true, so simply perform this check, if it's false you have no lowercase letters.

Comment: Does not allow for any letters except a-z --> Bad for most languages outside English

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would seem to be:

```
^[^a-z]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic:

`^[^a-z]*$`

Exclude empty lines:

`^[^a-z]+$`

Catering for exclusion of non-english chars (e.g. exclude a string containing à like 'VOILà'):

`^\P{Ll}*$`

---

*Expressions (e.g. JS):*

Single line:

`/^[^a-z]*$/`

Multi line:

`/^[^a-z]*$/m`

---

*Theory:*

`[a-z]` matches a character that is a,b,c,...z

`[a-z]*` matches a series of characters that are a,b,c,...z

`^[a-z]*` matches a series of characters that are **not** a,b,c...z

`^[^a-z]*$` matches a string only containing a series of characters that are not a,b,c,...z from beginning to end.

`^[^a-z]+$` ensures that there is at least one character that is not a,b,c,...z, and that the remaining characters are not a,b,c,...z in the string from beginning to end.

`^\P{Ll}*$` matches all Unicode characters in the 'letter' group that have an uppercase variant - see https://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: I guess you mean `[^a-z]` for the last 3 examples. `^[^a-z][^a-z]*$` is better written `^[^a-z]+$` and `^[^\p{Ll}]*$` <=> `^\P{Ll}*$` (Note: `\p{lL}` includes english letters as well)

Comment: Thank you! All amazing feedback!

Comment: @Dan I've found `^\P{Ll}*$` doesn't work for non-latin languages such as Japanese and Chinese (the trick being 'that have an uppercase variant').  Do you happen to know of one to use for those languages?

Comment: @simpleCoder sorry, no, I have no idea. How does upper casing work in those languages if the uppercase is not a variant of lowercase? Sounds like a slightly different paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="ABCcDEF";
if ( preg_match ("/[a-z]/",$str ) ){
    echo "Lowercase found\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `(s == uppercase(s))` --> string is all caps?