# Using Javascript, how to capitalize each word in a String excluding acronyms ?

Tags: javascript, string

I was trying the following solution,which works great, but I have an additional requirement where I need to exclude the acronyms (words in all caps) from the conversion.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(lower) {
    return (lower ? this.toLowerCase() : this).replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

Any idea on how this can be done ?

Comment: Try using a regular expression to check for all capital letters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323988/determine-if-string-is-all-caps-with-regular-expression

Comment: Wait, if you're trying to capitalize all the words in a string excluding words that are all caps...can't you just use `.toUpperCase`?  That is if your input is `"Hello HTML goodbye"`, and you want the output to be `"HELLO HTML GOODBYE"`, you can just use `.toUpperCase`...could you clarify?

Comment: For input string "Hello HTML goodbye", I would expect "Hello HTML Goodbye".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cats

```
"i like cats. So does the ASPCA. Cats like milk, tho.".replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });

//=> "I Like Cats. So Does The ASPCA. Cats Like Milk, Tho."
```

---

Here's a nice function for you to use too

```
function capitalize(s) { return s.toUpperCase(); }

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.toString().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, capitalize);
};
```

Now you can call `.capitalize` directly on a string

```
var s = "i like cats. So does the ASPCA. Cats like milk, tho.";

s.capitalize();
//=> "I Like Cats. So Does The ASPCA. Cats Like Milk, Tho."
```

---

The RegExp

- `\b` - match a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (zero-width)
- `[a-z]` - match one character a-z (case-sensitive)

Flags

- `g` - global; match *all* instances of this expression

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for the solution. How is the regex working to exclude the acronyms ? I see that you are trying to replace all the characters covered by /\b[a-z]/g. Could you maybe explain this regex a bit more ? That would be really helpful.

Comment: This won't work for non acronyms for example `hELLo` will return `HELLo`... not what your looking for

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee  I provided more details about the regexp

Comment: @naomik Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this
             .replace(/(\w*[a-z0-9_]+\w*)/g, function(a) {
                 return a.toLowerCase()
             }).replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { 
                 return a.toUpperCase();
             });
};
```

The first part finds all the words that have at least one word character that's not a capital letter - i.e. acronyms.

Comment: This is a nice solution, thanks for the answer and the explanation of the code. Very helpful.

Comment: Why is this defined on the prototype if it operates on the `lower` parameter?