# Find the line with all caps in Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all lines that are all caps using regex, and so far I've tried this:

```
re.findall(r'\b\n|[A-Z]+\b', kaizoku)
```

So far my database is as follows:

```
TRAFALGAR LAW
You shall not be the pirate king.
MONKEY D LUFFY
Now!
DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:
Noooooo!
```

I want it to return

```
TRAFALGAR LAW
MONKEY D LUFFY
DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:
```

But it's returning something else.
(Namely this:

```
TRAFALGAR
LAW
Y
MONKEY
D
LUFFY
N
DOFLAMINGO'
S
UNDERLINGS:
N
```

**EDIT**
So far I really think the best fit for the answer is @Jan's answer

```
rx = re.compile(r"^([A-Z ':]+$)\b", re.M)
rx.findall(string)
```

**EDIT2** Found out what's wrong, thanks!

Comment: What's "something else"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string is upper, lower, or mixed case in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222855/check-if-string-is-upper-lower-or-mixed-case-in-python)

Comment: `DOFLAMINGO'S` has a quote in it... output & expected output in detail please ([mcve])

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2323988/8881141 Also no effort, when somebody like me, who doesn't no anything about regex, finds it in less than a minute.

Comment: @Piinthesky: I tried those solutions, and it returned nothing for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```
import re

string = """TRAFALGAR LAW
You shall not be the pirate king.
MONKEY D LUFFY
Now!
DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:
Noooooo!
"""

rx = re.compile(r"^([A-Z ':]+$)", re.M)

UPPERCASE = [line for line in string.split("\n") if rx.match(line)]
print(UPPERCASE)
```

Or:

```
rx = re.compile(r"^([A-Z ':]+$)", re.M)

UPPERCASE = rx.findall(string)
print(UPPERCASE)
```

Both will yield

```
['TRAFALGAR LAW', 'MONKEY D LUFFY', "DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:"]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Very true, thanks for spotting it. Updated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thank you, but it doesn't do well if one line goes A SERVANT.

Comment: @Jan What does ': means?

Answer (score 5):

### Brief

No need for regex, python has the method [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)

> Return true if all cased characters<sup>[4]</sup> in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.
>
> <sub>[4] Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).</sub>

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/JXoqzA)

```
a = [
    "TRAFALGAR LAW",
    "You shall not be the pirate king.",
    "MONKEY D LUFFY",
    "Now!",
    "DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:",
    "Noooooo!",
]

for s in a:
    print s.isupper()
```

#### Result

```
True
False
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[A-Z\W]` to check for any uppercase letters along with non alphanumeric characters:

```
import re
s = ["TRAFALGAR LAW", "You shall not be the pirate king.", "MONKEY D LUFFY", "Now!", "DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:", "Noooooo!"]
new_s = [i for i in s if re.findall('^[A-Z\d_\W]+$', i)]
```

Output:

```
['TRAFALGAR LAW', 'MONKEY D LUFFY', "DOFLAMINGO'S UNDERLINGS:"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[A-Z\d_\W]` be better as it includes digits and underscore (in the case that they may be used)?